# Select Month in Oracle Query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

I tried the below query in oracle

```
select cast(TO_DATE (cal.MONTH,'MM') AS varchar2(30)) as result 
FROM  JOBCONTROL_USER.ods_calendar_weeks cal  
WHERE cal.YEAR NOT IN (0, 9999)
```

it gives result in `dd-mon-yy` format. Now I want only `mon` from the result, how can I achieve this without using `to_char()`?

Comment: "*without using to_char()*" - why would you want to do that?

Comment: What data type is `cal.month`?  Is that a `date`?  Or a `varchar2`?  Or something else?  I'm guessing it's a `date` but you can't pass a `date` to the `to_date` function, you can only pass a string.  Oracle will implicitly cast the `date` to a `varchar2` but then Oracle is doing implicitly what you say you want to avoid with `to_char` for some reason.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I'm using a tool which converts oracle query to `ANSI Standard SQL` and that tool suggest me to use `convert()` or `cast()` instead of `to_char()`.

Comment: @JustinCave : `cal.month` is of type `varchar2` and its value comes between 1 to 12.

Comment: So you want the abbreviated month name that corresponds to the month number held as a string in your field? Why, and in which language?

Comment: @AlexPoole : I already answered why and i'm not clear what you are trying to ask in `in which language`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're avoiding Oracle functions and the month number is stored on its own as a `varchar2` field, then you could brute-force it:

```
select case cast(month as number)
    when 1 then 'Jan'
    when 2 then 'Feb'
    when 3 then 'Mar'
    when 4 then 'Apr'
    when 5 then 'May'
    when 6 then 'Jun'
    when 7 then 'Jul'
    when 8 then 'Aug'
    when 9 then 'Sep'
    when 10 then 'Oct'
    when 11 then 'Nov'
    when 12 then 'Dec'
  end as mon
from ods_calendar_weeks cal
where cal.year not in (0, 9999);
```

But you're having to specify the language; you don't get Oracle's conversion of the month to the NLS date language. Which might be a bonus or a problem depending on your context.

I'd be tempted to put the conversions into a look-up table instead and join to that; or to add the month name as a separate column on the table, as a virtual column in 11g.

Comment: +1, is there any other way of doing it without `case when` and `to_char()`?

Comment: If you aren't able to use any Oracle functions then you have to manually convert the number to a name somewhere. You could have a function to do that which still might use case; or a virtual column; or a look-up table as I suggested, which might be simplest for your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(cal.Month,'month')
              ) AS result
FROM  JOBCONTROL_USER.ods_calendar_weeks cal  
WHERE cal.YEAR NOT IN (0, 9999);
```

This will gives month. the to_char() is a function which has two arguments 1. Column name ans 2. Month. Column name is of date data type so we have to convert the date into character data type and we required only the month so the second column will describes what will be extracted from the date. Finally the result is displayed as a character datatype. This query will returns the months name if year neither 0 nor 9999.

Comment: Smart003 : I can't use `to_char()`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Without any text, answers like this appears in the Low Quality Review Queue. This means that there's a risk your answer is deleted by what's known as robo-reviewers. I don't know anything about this topic so I can't really tell if it is low quality or not, but I suggest you add a small paragraph stating what is different from your code and the OP's post. Preferably with an explanation of why this works and the other doesn't.

Comment: This also just gives the month number, which is what the OP is starting with in the `cal.month` column, rather than the month name.

Comment: Sid M: to_char has to used to retrieve the data from a date;try 'month' instead of 'mm' as 'month' will returns name of the month where as 'mm' will returns the number of month

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CAST(TO_DATE (cal.MONTH,'MM') AS varchar2(30))) as RESULT 
FROM  JOBCONTROL_USER.ods_calendar_weeks cal  
WHERE cal.YEAR NOT IN (0, 9999)
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: With the cast to `varchar2` this gets `ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source` - you can't extract from a string. Without the cast it gives the month number, which is what the OP is starting with in the `cal.month column`, rather than the month name.